# Implicit conversion of 0 to enums

Tags: c#, enums, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In C#, a decimal literal `0` can be implicitly converted to an enum (or a nullable whose underlying type is an enum).

[C# spec](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/conversions.md#implicit-conversions), current version on GitHub

> An implicit enumeration conversion
>   permits the decimal_integer_literal 0 to be converted to any enum_type
>   and to any nullable_type whose underlying type is an enum_type. In the
>   latter case the conversion is evaluated by converting to the
>   underlying enum_type and wrapping the result (Nullable types).

[ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf), section 11.2.4 Implicit enumeration conversions

> An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal
>   0 (or 0L, etc.) to be converted to any enum-type and to any
>   nullable-value-type whose underlying type is an enum-type. In the
>   latter case the conversion is evaluated by converting to the
>   underlying enum-type and wrapping the result (§9.3.11)

Base on this, all of the following examples should be legal. This example is from Eric Lippert's article [The Root Of All Evil, Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2006/03/28/the-root-of-all-evil-part-one/).

```
enum E
{
  X, Y, Z
}

E e1 = E.X;
E e2 = 0 | E.X;
E e3 = E.X | 0;
E e4 = E.X | 0 | 0;
E e5 = 0 | E.X | 0;
```

However, as Eric explains, the following case should be illegal:

```
E e6 = 0 | 0 | E.X;
```

The reason is that `0 | 0 | E.X` is the same as `(0 | 0) | E.X` and `0 | 0` is not a literal, but a compile-time constant that has the value 0. The same is true for the following cases:

```
E e7 = 1 - 1;
E e8 = 2 - 1 - 1 + 0;
E e9 = (0L & 1);
```

However, these all work fine; `e6`, `e7`, `e8`, and `e9` in this example have the value `E.X`.

Why is that? Is there a (newer) specification in the standard that says compile-time constants that are 0 can be also implicitly converted to any enum or is this something the compiler does without following the specifications exactly?

Comment: Things are probably have changed since 2006. In which version of C# it works and in which it doesn't ?

Comment: I think it's the same in all. Works with .NET framework 4.6.2 and .NET core 2.1.

Comment: @MariusBancila you need to be very cautious with language here... this is a **compiler** thing - ".NET framework 4.6.2 and .NET core 2.1" are *runtimes* - frankly, they don't even get a vote. It is the *compiler* version that matters here.

Comment: Sure, you're right about that. I've tried with everything, from ISO-2 to C# 7.3. They all work the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noted, `0 | 0 | E.X` gets bound as `(0 | 0) | E.X`.

Eric noted that the compiler doesn't follow the spec for `0 | 0 | E.X`:

> After we've got a complete parse tree we walk through the parse tree making sure that all the types work out. Unfortunately the initial type binding pass bizarrely enough does arithmetic optimizations. It detects the 0|something and aggressively replaces it with just something , so as far as the compiler is concerned, the sixth case is the same as the second, which is legal. Argh!

Eric notes in the comments:

> but (7-7)|E.X does correctly produce an error

It seems that Roslyn is a bit smarter about folding constants than the native compiler was. It's likely that they were aiming for efficiency here, without being concerned about preserving bug-for-bug behaviour in an edge-case.

Exactly the same problem now seems to apply to `7 - 7`, or any other expression which the compiler can evaluate to `0` during that initial type binding pass, for the same reason.

I think the constant folding is happening [here](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Operators.cs,1565):

```
newValue = FoldNeverOverflowBinaryOperators(kind, valueLeft, valueRight);
if (newValue != null)
{
    return ConstantValue.Create(newValue, resultType);
}
```

As you can see, this creates a new `ConstantValue`. So `(0 | 0) | E.X` gets folded to `0 | E.X`, where that first `0` is a constant. When the compiler comes to fold `0 | E.X`, it isn't aware that the `0` is not a literal `0` in the original source, but is instead a compiler-generated constant, and so folds it as if you had written `0 | E.X` originally.

Exactly the same is happening with your other examples, and I think it's done by the same bit of code. `1 - 1` gets folded into a constant `0`, as do the others. This will happen with any expression that the compiler can evaluate to `0` at compile-time.